# html-pdf adjust content to fit inside the PDF

Tags: node.js, express, pdf, html-pdf

I'm receiving a HTML for an API, I cannot change its content, but I can add  styles. I created a NodeJS/Express backend to transform this HTML to a PDF. However, it is not formatted inside the PDF.

The example below shows the issue:

```
const pdf = require('html-pdf');

let form = `
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
`
let options = {
    format: 'Letter'
};
pdf.create(form, options).toBuffer(function(err, buffer){
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Length': buffer.length
    });
    return res.end(buffer);
});
```

The response is a PDF with the content outside the PDF file (image below). Is there a way to adjust the `html-pdf` to fix the content?

[image]

Comment: And do what? That for most applications is exactly correct. AAAAAAAAAA... is not a word and there is no breakpoints.

Comment: How can I ```html-pdf``` library to continue the long string in a new line?